# Why creating an anonymous Runnable subclass for Threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, coding-style

When working with Threads, it is fairly common to write something like this:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() { /* ... */ }
};
new Thread(r).start();
```

This is all nice and correct, but I believe the same could be achieved in a more performant and easy way:

```
new Thread()
{
    public void run() { /* ... */ }
}.start();
```

However, I almost never see anything like this in code examples using `Threads` and `Runnable`. Is there any technical or style-related reason to use the first example instead of the second?

Comment: Because maybe your class does already `extends` another class.

Comment: Something I noticed about `Thread` is unlike `Runnable` it is not needed to invoke the swing components. And using much `threads` increases CPU usage more than `runnables`

Comment: More performant?  Probably not.  Easier?  Yes, but then that's what makes it so damned hard to maintain the legacy code that I have to work with every day  Somebody took the easy way out instead of taking the time to make it flexible, testable, scalable, extensible,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

```
Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() { /*your code */ }
};
new Thread(r).start();
new Thread(r).start();
new Thread(r).start();
new Thread(r).start();
```

is equal to

```
new Thread()
{
    public void run() { /* ... */ }
}.start()
new Thread()
{
    public void run() { /* ... */ }
}.start();

new Thread()
{
    public void run() { /* ... */ }
}.start();
new Thread()
{
    public void run() { /* ... */ }
}.start();
```

They are not exactly equal. In the first case all threads share the same runnable in the second, they don't. In the first case, write to a volatile field (or if a happens-before exists), will be visible to other threads.

Comment: Nope... Not exactly true.. In the first case all threads share the same *runnable* in the second, they don't. In the first case, write to a *volatile* field (or if a *happens-before* exists), will be visible to other threads.

Comment: Its *almost* equivalent to `new Thread(new Runnable)`

Answer (score 1):

Basically `Thread` class also `extends` the same `Runnable` interface so same behavior of the `Thread` class you can also achieve by implementing `Runnable` interface insated directly extending `Thread` class and implementing `run` method.
Moreover you can extend some other class and implement more `interface` also.